# How to get Airport code dynamically when a city is selected?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get Airport codes associated with the cities.

code that i have is for countries, state and cities But i also need when i select city there should be Airport Name or code.

code Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/txzui?file=/src/App.js

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and errors need to be included in the question, not just linked off-site.  Please also indicate specifically what isn't working as expected in the code.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.